# How to fix a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

My code results in an error where I do not know how to fix it. I tried putting in print statements but It wont even make it that far. The error occurs

Here is the exact error

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
        at ca.on.oicr.pinery.lims.gsle.GsleClient.getOrders(GsleClient.java:720)
```

Line 720 is the second for loop

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: You're adding to `orders` inside a loop that's looping over the elements of `orders`, that's what causes the exception. Don't modify a collection you're looping over inside the loop. Likewise with `samples`.

Comment: You cannot modify (add or remove) the collection when you are looping over it. You are trying to add a order to orders. You cannot do that.

Comment: Take a look a this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38998115/3380878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) if you want add or remove elements from a list while iterating over the elements. This is assuming that your `orders` is a List

So, your code would look something like this --

```
ListIterator<Order> it = orders.listIterator();

while ( it.hasNext() ) {
      Order ord = it.next();

      if ( ) // some condition
        it.remove(); // This wil remove the element that we just got using the next() method
      if ( ) // some other condition
        it.add(new Order()); // THis inserts the element immediately before the next call to next()
}
```

Comment: in my case, would I be removing? and I am creating a new instance of Order everytime?

Comment: If the `orders` is a List, then you can use the `ListIterator` and use the `add` method

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to manipulate the content of `sample` while iterating over its contents. To fix this kind of problems, use immutable collections, or pretend they are.

What you want to do is, while iterating over `samples`, build up another collection with the one you want, and modify this other collection instead of your original one.

Comment: I think he has two problems `samples` and `orders` inside the samples loop he are changing the content of orders too.

Comment: Yes, I wish that default collections in Java were immutable, to prevent this kind of behaviour... (Like they are in Scala) - we need more functional programming concepts into our OO ways :)

Comment: to fix this would I just put the orders.add(order) outside the second forloop but within the first first loop? would that solve it?

Comment: or do I have to reconstruct this whole thing from scratch

Comment: You would have to rewrite it: You cannot modify a collection while iterating over it! The problem would still exist if you had only one collection (orders)

Comment: sorry I am just a bit confused as to how to fix this then?

Comment: While inside a for loop, you cannot modify the collection you're doing the loop on (removing or adding elements). Instead, you can build a new collection that you declare before the loop, and you stick the elements you want in.

Comment: Or you can use the solution provided by Kal, it would probably work, but I still think it's bad practice to modify your collection while iterating it.

Comment: by build a new collection, you mean to create two new empty sets and a new list, and input what I want into those lists by looping through my existing maps?